# javaagents: transformation order

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm, javaagents

In my project I'd like to transform bytecode in two stages. The order is important.

1. Firstly I need to change methods definition
2. then the way methods are called

For example

1. change definition from `String hello()` to `String hello(String s)`
2. change calling from `Hello.hello()` to `Hello.hello("newArgument")`

I managed to add transformer, which do the first step.

```
public class MyJavaAgent {

    private static Instrumentation instrumentation;

    public static void premain(String args, Instrumentation inst)
            throws Exception {
        instrumentation = inst;
        instrumentation.addTransformer(new MyClassFileTransformer());
    }
}
```

My question is: Can I add new transformer in that way:

```
public class MyJavaAgent {

    private static Instrumentation instrumentation;

    public static void premain(String args, Instrumentation inst)
            throws Exception {
        instrumentation = inst;
        instrumentation.addTransformer(new MyClassFileTransformer());
        instrumentation.addTransformer(new MyClassFileTransformer2());
    }
}
```

and be sure that the `MyClassFileTransformer` do his job before `MyClassFileTransformer2`?

Comment: See [`Instrumentation.transform`](http://goo.gl/lthbb)

Answer (score 3):

There is a simple way to test this... Add a System.out instruction in the transform method of each of the Transformer classes that would output unique messages the respective classes.  Then check out the order in which the outputs are obtained on the console. If you get the unique message for Transformer1 before that of Transformer2, then yes, the transform methods are called in order.

This is what i did...

```
package Test;

import java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer;
import java.lang.instrument.IllegalClassFormatException;
import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;
import java.security.ProtectionDomain;

public class TransFormerTest  {


    public TransFormerTest() {
        super();
    }

    public static void premain(String agentArguments, Instrumentation instrumentation) {
        instrumentation.addTransformer(new Transformer1());
        instrumentation.addTransformer(new Transformer2());
    }
}

class Transformer1 implements ClassFileTransformer {
    public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, String className, Class redefiningClass, ProtectionDomain domain, byte[] bytes) throws IllegalClassFormatException {
        System.out.println(className + "one"); // one for Transformer
        return bytes;
    }
}

class Transformer2 implements ClassFileTransformer {
    public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, String className, Class redefiningClass, ProtectionDomain domain, byte[] bytes) throws IllegalClassFormatException {
        System.out.println(className + "two"); // two for Transformer 2
        return bytes;
    }
}
```

So each time a class is loaded and the transformers are invoked, you should see the name of the class being printed twice, first with **one** as a suffix, then **two** as a suffix.

I tested this theory out with a simple Hello World program... and this is my output::

```
Test/Transformer2 - one
sun/launcher/LauncherHelper - one
sun/launcher/LauncherHelper - two
java/lang/Enum - one
java/lang/Enum - two
HelloWorld - one
HelloWorld - two
java/lang/Void - one
java/lang/Void - two
Hello World
java/lang/Shutdown - one
java/lang/Shutdown - two
java/lang/Shutdown$Lock - one
java/lang/Shutdown$Lock - two
```

So, it seems like it does maintain the order.

That being said, have you considered chaining the transform methods? For instance...

```
public class TransFormerTest  {

    public TransFormerTest() {
        super();
    }

    public static void premain(String agentArguments, Instrumentation instrumentation) {
        instrumentation.addTransformer(new Transformer());
    }
}

class Transformer implements ClassFileTransformer {
    public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, String className, Class redefiningClass, ProtectionDomain domain, byte[] bytes) throws IllegalClassFormatException {
        byte[] bytes2 =  privateTransformer(className, bytes);
        return bytes2;
    }

    private byte[] privateTransformer(String className, byte[] bytes) {
        System.out.println(className + " - one");
            // TODO add code for First Transformation.
        byte[] bytes2 = privateTransformer2(className, bytes);
        return bytes2;
    }

    private byte[] privateTransformer2(String className, byte[] bytes) {
        System.out.println(className + " - two");
            // TODO add code for Second Transformation.
        return bytes;
    }
}
```

This would still achieve similar results and this is sure to maintain the order in which the transformation is likely to take place.